# How can I find all documents that match value in array using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a sample document below. I would like to find all documents with contact starting with Dr.

```
{
        "addressLine1": "Grand Central",
        "addressLine2": "",
        "city": "New York",
        "contact": [0: "Dr. Who", 
                    1: "Dr. Dre"],
        "email": "12@yahoo.com",
        "phoneNumber": "",
        "postcode": "",
        "service": "Dentist",
        "status": true,
        "supplier": ""
    }
```

I've tried with the command below but i'm not having any success.

```
const result = await client.db("Test").collection("test")
    .find({contact:{ $elemMatch: "Dr."}});
```

If I don't have any filters all the documents appear, I would like to narrow down my search results with the criteria above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so if at least 1 in the contact array starts with Dr.?

Comment: yes, I would like to find documents with specific contact information even if they are jus partial matches.

Comment: `.find({ contact: /Dr./ })`. May need to escape the period in the regex, I'm not entirely sure off the top of my head.

Comment: something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/qVK7jKC2mOp ?

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion I had to add this to see the documents

 await result.forEach((document) => {
      console.log(document);
    });

Comment: @user20042973 if you anchor that regex, like `/^Dr./` it can use an index.

Comment: Ah yep, missed the caret when writing that out earlier. Thanks for that and the playground link. Agreed about index usage as well as being logically consistent with what OP requested. (Feel free to add the answer, I have no intention to)